# Perl AJAX stripping html characters out of string?

Tags: html, ajax, perl, stripping

I have a Perl program that is reading html tags from a text file. (im pretty sure this is working because when i run the perl program on the command line it prints out the HTML like it should be.)
I then pass that "html" to the web page as the return to an ajax request. I then use innerHTML to stick that string into a div.

Heres the problem:
all the text information is getting to where it needs to be. but the "<" ">" and "/" are getting stripped.

any one know the answer to this?

Comment: What do you get if you alert() or console.log() your Perl's "html" from the Javascript?

Comment: This is an extremely vague question. You really need to track down where the data is changing into something you don't want. It could be something wrong with your server or any client side Javascript you have running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear to me without some code and data examples, but if it is what it vaguely sounds like, you may need to HTML-encode your text (e.g. using [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.66/lib/HTML/Entities.pm)).

I'm kind of surprized that's an issue with inserting into innerHTML, but without specific example, that's the first thing which comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

There could be a mod on the server that is removing special characters.  Are you running Apache? (I doubt this is what's happening).

If something is being stripped on the client-side, it is most likely in the response handler portion of the AJAX call.  Show your code where you stick the string in the div.